# How to simplify redudant code jQuery hover()

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to implement jQuery hover() and my code is working good. In order to run addClass() and removeClass() with jQuery hover() I have to define selector as shown in my code below. But its kind of wasted to declare selector twice, how can I simplify this redundant code to declare selector only once.

```js
$('.main ul li a, .content-wrap .content').hover(
  function() {
    //start redundant code
    var mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
    var mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    var contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    //end redundant code
    mainData.addClass('active');
    contentData.addClass('active');
    contentData.siblings().addClass('hidden');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  },
  function() {
    //start redundant code
    var mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
    var mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    var contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    //end redundant code
    mainData.removeClass('active');
    contentData.removeClass('active');
    contentData.siblings().removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.content-wrap {
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: yellow;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

.content {
  padding: 80px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in;
  position: relative;
}

.tool-tip {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in;
}

.content.active .tool-tip {
  opacity: 1;
}

.main li a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.content.hidden {
  background-color: gray;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item1">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item2">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item3">item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item4">item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-hover="item5">item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content-wrap">
  <div class="content red" data-hover="item1">
    <p>content 1</p>
    <div class="tool-tip">
      content 1 is active
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content green" data-hover="item2">
    <p>content 2</p>
    <div class="tool-tip">
      content 2 is active
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content blue" data-hover="item3">
    <p>content 3</p>
    <div class="tool-tip">
      content 3 is active
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content purple" data-hover="item4">
    <p>content 4</p>
    <div class="tool-tip">
      content 4 is active
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content brown" data-hover="item5">
    <p>content 5</p>
    <div class="tool-tip">
      content 5 is active
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using only one function argument of `hover()` which will fire for both mouseout and mouseenter.

Then use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for most of this and  check the event `type`  as conditional for anything specific that isn't generic.

```
$('.main ul li a, .content-wrap .content').hover(function(e) {
  //start redudant code
  var mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
  var mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
  var contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');

  //don't seem to be  dependent on which event
  mainData.toggleClass('active');
  mainData.toggleClass('active');
  contentData.toggleClass('active');
  contentData.siblings().toggleClass('hidden');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');

  // use this for anything more specifc
  var eventType = e.type;
  if (eventType === 'mouseout') {
    // anything specific to mouseout
  } else {
    // anything specific to mouseenter
  }

})
```

Comment: It looks simple than I though, I didnt notice that toggleClass() can be trigger when mouseout. Thank you for suggestion

Comment: But I was wondering why it cannot give class active when I hover the object. When I check with inspect element in my browser it didnt adding class active

Comment: Was it there to start with perhaps and thus got removed instead? You can also use `e.type=== 'mouseout'` to create a boolean flag to pass to toggleClass to force it to add/remove depending on the boolean

Comment: its working, but it should be give class active to all children in .main and .content when hovering

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox site that allows forking if it's being a problem

Comment: am creating like this https://jsfiddle.net/2fpoyfxw/1/
it works good, but Im trying to give class active to any object I hover

Comment: I'm not really sure what expected behavior is but I suspect you want to `index` the link and associated content and only add to those matches and remove from others

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to different function

```
$('.main ul li a, .content-wrap .content').hover(
  function() {
    doHover.apply(this, true);
  },
  function() {
    doHover.apply(this, false);
  }
);

function doHover(isHover) {
    var mainAnchor = $(this).data('hover');
    var mainData = $('.main li a[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    var contentData = $('.content-wrap .content[data-hover= ' + mainAnchor + ']');
    mainData.toggleClass('active', isHover);
    contentData.toggleClass('active', isHover);
    contentData.siblings().toggleClass('hidden', isHover);
    $(this).toggleClass('active', isHover);
}
```